# When would I use TransactionScope and Transaction in SQL

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between TransactionScope in dot net and Transaction in SQL

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            int i = 0;
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
                i = 1;                
            }
            Response.Write(i.ToString());
        }
```

I get the value 1 displayed by Response.Write(). Why? scope.Complete wasnt  executed. Hence the i value should rollback to 0;

Comment: 1. TransactionScope can be used not only for SQL , but also for other stuff

Comment: I have tried using a transactionScope block  and within the block
I have modified an integer value whose value retains even 
when scope.complete() method doesnt get executed.
Why doesnt the value of integer roll back?

Comment: We need to see a code sample to answer that

Comment: Create two queries - make the second one fail and check that the first was rolled back - very simple to do.

Comment: How do I make it fail? I have tried using a wrong table name.

Comment: Use a different table and put a bad entry in it... dozens of ways to do this if you stop and think it through

Comment: Actually putting a table that doesnt exist rolls it back. But I am not sure if its the ideal way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9821/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-irishchieftain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same thing; TransactionScope is the newer .NET version and the recommened version to use if you are coding on ASPNET 2.0 upwards.

[TransactionScope Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            "Update1");

        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            "Update2");
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Check the link and snippet I gave you - you are not even calling the Complete method - and don't put this in a loop...

Comment: Shouldn't scope.Complete be inside the using (at the end) . Looks like this won't compile?